# optimized query find in mongoDB and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, bulk

I am trying to use bulk for find operation to optimize my code with mongoDB, here is an example for the code am using to obtain my result.
I am not using 4 variables, I habe mentioned only a and b to give a concrete example

```
 var bulk = initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
 if ((a === '')&&(b==='')){
   bulk.find()
 }
else if ((a !== '')&&(b !=='')){
   bulk.find({'b': b, 'a':a})
 }
 else if ( a===''){
  bulk.find({'b': b})
 }
else{
  bulk.find({'a':a})
 }
 bulk.execute();
```

Do you have better suggestions to use in my code?? Thank you in advance

Comment: So you end up doing only one find operation. Why are you doing a find for bulk?

Comment: I want to optimze my code, I have other operations to do with the result found, so, with bulk.execute I will write it only once. it is the same find operation, only sometimes the variable exist sometimes not

Comment: Please provide more details on how you want the optimizations to be? What exactly are you trying to do? What is the problem you wanna optimize?

Comment: the number of queries find is the problem that i want to optimze, I said that i have more than two variables to use in the query find (not only a and b)